# Custom Maven plugins and libraries

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Currently, I have a few custom maven plugins which use the same libraries (JARs) as my application which uses it. 
It is pertinent to mention that the libraries are also custom libraries developed by us and not 3rd party.
I want to let go of these libraries and integrate all of them directly inside my application source code - just have one problem - what do I do with 
the maven plugins which use them.
Is there a way I can use the application source code (after integrating the libraries) while compiling / running the maven plugins?

Comment: Do you want to have within the same multi-project: 1. library code 2. plugin code using library code 3. plugin execution?

Comment: Yes. This may sound strange, but maintaining all these artifacts separately just for one application is becoming a nightmare - rebuilding everything, maintaining the versions etc - all this just to maintain one single application which in itself is not too complex. I just want to have one project to maintain  - that's the whole idea.

Comment: Clear. I have same issue in my project. My concept is wrap library code in `java.util.function.Consumer` and create a generic plugin which finds concrete `Consumer` by `java.util.ServiceLoader` and run it. But it will take me day or two to provide regular answer here.

Comment: Ok, but how do I access these libraries then at compile time and runtime from the application itself. As I said these libraries are shared by both the application directly and by the plugins (which are used at build time on this application)

Comment: Plugin, I will name it mapconsumer-maven-plugin, will be released separately. The plugin will depend only on JDK. The plugin will find correct Consumer on classpath by ServiceLoader and call method `accept`. All required parameters will be passed in Map object. You have to implement own Consumer which will accept a map parameter and do what you need

Comment: The consumer in that case would have to be inside the application (as it would need the library source code to work).  In that case what you are effectively saying is to put all the plugin logic in the application and just call a particular service through the plugin.   To give you an example, one of the libraries helps the plugin and the application to connect to the database.

Comment: Yes, you are following my idea. However, phrase "...put all plugin logic in the application..." is not precise. The logic don't to be part of application (part of WAR for example). It may be part of build, for example Maven module, part of multi-project but not included in final application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110155/discussion-between-abby-and-michaldo).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't go on this path because of dependency hell etc, but if you really need to you could create a jar containing the source files (see https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) and then in the project you need to source unpack it like this https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/using-dependencies-sources.html.

ps: what is the reason to drop the libraries and instead use the source code?

Comment: What about the different maven plugins which use the same libraries?

Comment: You could perform the trick as described above. You copy the jar into the maven plugin, extract it to a source directory in target and include it in the compiler source path. Than you can continue with the normal build process.

Comment: I understand. But that would mean that I duplicate the source code of the libraries both in the application source code and my plugins source code (the libraries which are used by both of them). This may sound like a silly question - but is there a way to avoid this? These maven plugins are only used for this one application. Basically, I just want to make this application as standalone as possible.

Comment: Alternatives I see, (and I think you already have it like that) is that you have common libraries that are shared between the application and maven plugin, or the plugin could call exposed services of the application. That would mean of course that you have a running instance of your app when you execute the maven plugin.

Comment: I see. Is it somehow not possible that I make the source of the libraries as part of the application code and when I run the maven plugins, they call this source code (part of the application on which the plugin is run).